# hiding a message in xslt

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have this message in my xslt:

```
                <tr class="EnteteChapitreRouge" id="alert">
                <td colspan="3">
                  <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        &#160;Attention ! Une ou plusieurs ligne de cette prescription protocolée nécessitent d'etre modifiées &#160;
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
      </xsl:if>
```

I want to hide it when I click on a button, and let it back when I click again, is there a way ? I made a fuction javascript for this button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has **nothing** to do with dynamic effects on an HTML page.
XSLT script processes XML generated by the server and generates
(in this case) HTML file, which then is rendered by a browser.

And as far as showing or hiding of an HTML element is concerned,
adopt the following example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function showHide() {
      var x = document.getElementById("alert");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "table-row";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Text before.</p>
  <p><button onclick="showHide()">Show / Hide</button></p>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="2">
    <tr><td>Row before</td></tr>
    <tr id="alert"><td>&#160;Attention! ...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row after</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>Text after.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`showHide` function is responsible for hiding and showing of `alert` element.
Note that because in your example it is a table row, I used `table-row`
display style, instead of usually used `block`.

`Show / Hide` button executes this function on each click, causing hiding
or displaying of `alert` row.

Of course, respective parts of the above HTML snippet must be parts of
the XSLT script, but I repeat that XSLT processor is running (creating
the target HTML) **before** any action by the browser.

There are other methods to do this task, e.g. *jQuery* `toggle` function,
but you marked your question with *JavaScript* tag (not *jQuery*),
so I used plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo for your answer, it seems I didn't explain well my question :)  I had problem to display some informations from xslt in my function javascript, but it's clear now, thanks alot for your answer I appreciate it :)